# Reorder HTML elements by class, not by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, feed

Every example I have seen of reordering elements uses ID's to swap or insert.  However, I am getting a feed onto my site and don't have control over whether an ID is used.  I am trying to use blogger.com to write articles, feedburner to create the feed, and have it display on my personal website.  Here is what I have:

```
<li>
   <span class="headline">
      <a href="webpage.html">Article Link</a>
   </span>
   <p class="date">8/3/2012</p>
   <div> Brief article intro...</div>
</li>
```

Here is what I want:

```
<li>
   <p class="date">8/3/2012</p>
   <span class="headline">
      <a href="webpage.html">Article Link</a>
   </span>
   <div> Brief article intro...</div>
</li>
```

I understand examples I've seen like so:

```
$("#div2").insertAfter("#div3");
$("#div1").prependTo("#div2");
```

But I'm not sure how to accomplish this generically or in a loop so that I can swap only classes within a single parent element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a solution

```
$('li').each( function() {
    var $this = $( this );
    $this.prepend( $( '.date', $this ) ) ;
} );
```

it detaches the date element and inserts it at the first position in the `li`

Comment: This makes no sense to me really, but this works great.  Thank you so much!  Curious if you know the following:  "this" is referring to the "li" element?  Or perhaps there is a plain english way to walk through what this code is doing exactly.

Answer (score 1):

SHortest solution I can think of

```
$('.date').each( function() {
    $(this).parent().prepend(this);
})
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/xs7UG/